# Converting for-loop to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, try-catch

If I have the following working code:

```
List<MyClass> results = new List<MyClass>();

for(int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
  try{ results.Add(Fetch(source[i])); }
  catch(Exception ex){ results.Add(new MyClass("poof!")); }
...
public MyClass Fetch(Object source){ ... }
```

and would like to remake it into LINQ, how can I manage the *try-catch*? If I put it around the following expression, It's not going to poof me. My suggestion would be to migrate catching into the method but I'm not sure how optimal/recommended that is. Can one tell at all or is depending on specifics of the scenario?

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = source.Select(e => Fetch(e));

public MyClass Fetch(Object source){ try{ ... } catch(){ ... } }
```

It'd be cool with something like this pseudo-code. I'm thinking the method `.First()` and it's more-potent brother `.FirstOrDefault()`, but with additional capacity.

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = source.Select(e => Fetch(e)).Excepted(...);
```

Am I way off?

Comment: `.ToList()` will cause the query to run.

Comment: Under what conditions is an exception thrown? If you can filter before calling .Add() to ensure the exception will never occur, this logic gets a lot easier. As-is, it smells bad ("don't use exception handling for flow control")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to create your `Excepted` class, but you can create a `Select` method with two selectors, one for the error case:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector, Func<TSource, TResult> secondarySelector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        TResult nextValue;
        try
        {
            nextValue = selector(item);
        }
        catch
        {
            nextValue = secondarySelector(item);
        }

        yield return nextValue;
    }
}
```

Then it would allow you to do:

```
var results = source.Select(item => Fetch(item)
    , item => new MyClass("poof!"))
    .ToList();
```

Your secondary selector could also take the exception as a parameter, if that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to move the `try / catch` block into a separate method and use that method as the selector.

```
public MyClass FetchOrDefault(object source){ 
  try { 
    return Fetch(source);
  } catch (Exception ex) { 
    return new MyClass("poof");
  }
}

// Method call syntax
var e = source.Select(x => x.FetchOrDefault(x));

// LINQ syntax
var e = from x in source select FetchOrDefault(x);
```

Comment: why do you type faster than me?

Comment: @StanR. I probably drink more coffee :)

Comment: you don't have extension method syntax ;) `this MyClass source`

Comment: @StanR. He's probably assuming that it'll be in the definition of the class itself.

Comment: @Servy actually the more I look at the initial question the more I'm confused, he has return `MyClass` into an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @StanR. That's a typo. I'd rebuilt the example to fit the forum and forgot to change it. Sorry. Keen eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get the same behaviour as your original code from

```
List<String> results = source.Select(e => { try
                                            {
                                                return Fetch(e);
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception)
                                            {
                                                 return MyClass("poof");
                                            }
                                          }).ToList();
```

But I think you should reconsider using try/catch this way. It has a severe performance cost, and is not intended to handle non-exceptional cases. Better check first if `e` is fetchable and do something like

```
List<String> results = source.Where(e => IsFetchable(e))
                             .Select(e => Fetch(e))
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing something like that in a lambda.  If you have a selector that complex it should almost certainly be in a named method that is just called from `Select`.  It's just doing too much to be inlined.  (Not that it won't work.)

Comment: @Servy i tend to agree with you, i think me and Jens were just showing him a different way

Comment: @StanR. I don't really consider them "different ways" at all.  It's the same way, but without a highly desirable code refactor.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just do what you did already 
i.e. you can include code block.

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = source.Select(e =>
{
try
  {
    return Fetch(e);
  }
catch
 {
    return new MyClass("poof");
 }
}
);
```